# How to traverse the following JSON in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

So i am recieving a JSON string from a rest service which has the following structure-

```
{
    "map": {
        "Project [projectId=1, projectName=Project1]": [
            {
                "employeeId": 4,
                "employeeName": "fourthEmployee"
            }, {
                "employeeId": 3,
                "employeeName": "thirdEmployee"
            }
        ],
        "Project [projectId=2, projectName=Project2]": [
            {
                "employeeId": 4,
                "employeeName": "fourthEmployee"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

( for reference, this is the object type being made available by rest - `Map<Project,List<Employee>>`)

My question is, how do i display the data from this particular JSON onto the HTML page in the form of a table, using angularJS?

I do realise ng-repeat is to be used multiple times. Its just that using ng-repeat, i'm not able to get the values from JSON. Could someone reply with code, that would be really helpful thanks.

EDIT: As pointed out by Robert, the problem is i am unable to get values from the compound project data. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: You want one table to store everything? Or one table per project? The latter is fairly straightforward with multiple `ng-repeat`s

Comment: Please provide an example output of this JSON. If you want table per project then it's simple `ngRepeat` within `ngRepeat`. I suppose the main problem you're having is getting values from the compound project data. Is that the main problem? If so, you can easily do this by calling `.map()` on your array and parse those compounds and restructure. If that's the problem, let us know and we'll help you provide correct answer.

Comment: Yes Robert, the problem is i am unable to get values from the compound project data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on insufficient data let me provide a solution to the problem that I speculate OP is actually having.

### Compound project data problem

I suspect that the main problem you're having is not about using nested `ngRepeat` but parsing the compound data of your projects.

This means that before you try displaying your data, you have to parse it or *re-map* it to something that you can actually use in your view.

This example uses regular expression to parse individual project property values.

```
var rx = /^Project \[projectId=(\d+), projectName=(.+)\]$/i;
var result = [];
for(var p in data.map)
{
    if (data.map.hasOwnProperty(p) && rx.test(p))
    {
        var m = rx.exec(p);
        result.push({
            id: m[1],
            name: m[2],
            employees: data.map[p]
        });
    }
}
```

This is a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sua3ts26/) with your provided data that displays projects including their data.